# Coordinate from 2 vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, geometry

All,

Suppose I have two vectors U and V with 2 units and 1 unit length, respectively as shown in the sketch. The vector U is rotated by angle theta.

There are, at least two possible cases whereby vector U can go "up" or "down" as shown in the sketch.

My question is, having the above dataset is it possible to have a generic formula that can be transferred into Matlab to get the coordinate of point M?

the length of the vector U and V and angle theta are arbitrary.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Work out the trigonometry by hand, then you'll have a formula you can easily transfer to MATLAB.

Comment: To clarify, you want the coordinates of `M(x,y)` given an azimuth angle `theta` of vector `U` (known length) and its normal vector `V` (known length)?

Comment: Hi @Aristotelis, Yes that is correct. I have the correct answer below and now wanted to know more. Please see my additional comment on the accepted answer below.

Comment: @BeeTiau have a look at my edited answer below.

Comment: To automate the process, since I have thousands of points, what would be the best criteria to filter the vector V that goes "up" or "down"? what would be the logic to filter vector V?

Comment: What do you mean by "filter"?

Comment: What's the logic to determine whether M is directed 'up' or 'down'?

Comment: from the angle between `U` and `V`, i.e. `atan(V,U)`, we can obtain the direction of M whether it is clockwise or anticlockwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Pythogoras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) we know that

> M = sqrt(U^2 + V^2)

angle between M and U is

> alpha = arctan(V/U)

So then you know that the x- and y-coordinates for M are:

the "up" case:

> M = (sqrt(U^2 + V^2)*cos(theta + sign(cosd(theta))*arctan(V/U)), sqrt(U^2 + V^2)*sin(theta + sign(cosd(theta))*arctan(V/U)))

the "down" case:

> M = (sqrt(U^2 + V^2)*cos(theta - sign(cosd(theta))*arctan(V/U)), sqrt(U^2 + V^2)*sin(theta - sign(cosd(theta))*arctan(V/U)))

---

A second way to calculate this is to look add the length of `U` and `V` in the x and y direction, and sum them.

The coordinates of U are:

> (U*cos(theta), U*sin(theta))

To this coordinates we must add/substract the x-and y-coordinates of V. The length of V along x and y is:

> (abs(sin(theta)), abs(cos(theta))

Whether one should add or substract these from U is dependent on theta. In general we can write Vup and Vdown as

> Vup = (V*sign(-cos(theta))*sin(theta), V*sign(cos(theta))*cos(theta))
>
> Vdown = (V*sign(cos(theta))*sin(theta), V*sign(-cos(theta))*cos(theta))

then we can alway add U to Vup and Vdown. Finally

> Mup = U + Vup
>
> Mdown = U + Vdown

Comment: Thanks @ViG, appreciate your help. To automate the process, since I have thousands of points, what would be the best criteria to filter the one that goes "up" or "down"?

Comment: In the 2nd method, the Y-coordinate of Vdown will always be negative. Are you sure this is the correct behaviour?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I interpreted that in the "down" case `My < uy`, so it is indeed the behaviour I expect.

Comment: @BeeTiau You mean In which case to use up or down? I think that depends on the behaviour you want. Maybe (if possible) you can give an input and a desired output?  ps I also made an edit in the answer

Comment: I think you may have been mislead by the specific case presented in the diagram, and also the use of the word "down" instead of the more accurate "clockwise". There is no such constraint on `My`. Try it for some vector U in the second quadrant - the "down" vector will point *upwards*.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog it will with your formulas, but in mine, up always points up. But I indeed may have interpreted it too literally. Then it's up to OP to clarify further, I think.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog no worries, you weren't arrogant at all :)

Comment: Apologies if I came across as arrogant, I see what you mean now. *However* for the special case where U is vertical, both vectors would be zero - so yes it would be helpful if the OP clarified the meaning of "up"

Answer (score 2):

There is a more efficient solution.

The coordinates of the endpoints of `U` are given by:

`(U * cos(theta), U * sin(theta))`

For any vector `(x, y)` the *clockwise* perpendicular direction (i.e. the second diagram "down") is `(y, -x)`, and those of the *anti-clockwise* direction are minus these. Therefore the coordinates of `M` are given by:

- Anti-clockwise ("up"): `(U * cos(theta) - M * sin(theta), U * sin(theta) + M * cos(theta))`
- Clockwise ("down"): `(U * cos(theta) + M * sin(theta), U * sin(theta) - M * cos(theta))`

No need for calls to `arctan` or `sqrt` which are both very costly. Also you can compute `sin/cos` just once and use the results for both components.

Answer (score 1):

Just another compact solution

```
theta = 30;
L = 2;   % norm of U vector

U = L*[cosd(theta) ; sind(theta)];
Vup   = [-U(2) ;  U(1)] / L;  % Normal vectors, unit length
Vdown = [U(2)  ; -U(1)] / L;

Mup   = U + Vup;     % Two possible values of M
Mdown = U + Vdown;

% Bonus plot
figure
plot([0 U(1)] , [0 U(2)] , 'k-')
hold on; axis equal;
plot([0 Vup(1)]+U(1)   , [0 Vup(2)]+U(2) , 'r-')
plot([0 Vdown(1)]+U(1) , [0 Vdown(2)]+U(2) , 'r-')
text(Mup(1),Mup(2),'M_u_p')
text(Mdown(1),Mdown(2),'M_d_o_w_n')
```

[image]

Comment: This routine assumes that V is calculated from U. In the original question, the length of U and V are known. Or did I miss something here?

Comment: @BeeTiau, I am not sure, I went along with "Suppose I have two vectors U and V with 2 units and 1 unit length" and that V is orthogonal to U. If V is given, the problem is even easier I guess...`M = U + V`. Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score -1):

You can exploit the properties of the cross product of `Uinit` and `Urot`. The sign of the product will inform you on the orientation of the resulting vector.

Supposing that the origin is `O(0,0)`, your initial vector is `Uinit(x1,y1)` and your final vector is `Urot(x2,y2)`. Also `M(x,y)` can be calculated easily.

If you want to filter the rotated vectors `Urot` that ended up 'above' or 'below' `M` compared to the previous orientation of your triangle, you can take the following cross products:
`M cross Uinit` and `M cross Urot`.
If their sign is the same then the resulting rotated vector didn't cross the line OM and the opposite if the sign is different.